# onhashchange vs pushState

Tags: javascript, hash, browser-history, pushstate

I am creating an internal dashboard on my site which is only accessible to logged in users and therefore is not indexable / crawlable by search engines.  This dashboard is mainly a single-page app.  Also, I don't care (at least I don't *think* I care) about having pretty urls: there is no progressive enhancement - if javascript is disabled, then the dashboard is not functional.

What I need is the ability to navigate using the back / forward button between different states - for instance, various modals that are opened. And very importantly, I need to be able to link *externally* to the specific state of the dashboard (e.g. modal A was open in this configuration) - e.g. via emails to users containing links to the dashboard.

Given all this, is there any preference to "old school" hash bangs (#!) vs html5 pushState? pushState will require me to use something like history.js for older browser support anyway.  And architecturally speaking, if my dashboard is at the following url:

```
http://example.com/dashboard
```

won't I have to perform nearly identical operations to resolve to a particular modal state regardless of whether I'm using pushState or onhashchange? In other words:

```
http://example.com/dashboard#!modalA/state1
```

or

```
http://example.com/dashboard/modalA/state1
```

both of which will require parsing client side (done by a framework) to figure out how to display the current dashboard state.  My backend controller would still be mapping to /dashboard/* for any dashboard url since all of the state concern is handled on the client.

Am I missing something? Not that it should matter, but I am using [CanJS](http://canjs.com/) which supports both hash events and pushState.

Note: my question is not specific to Google's hashbang proposal, but to the general use of the # (onhashchange).

Comment: Well if you have multiple pages I would suggest to use pushState over hashtags because if you have a page, for example /dashboard/settings, when the user refreshes the page, the server can read that they're requesting the settings page and the server can spit it out, rather than having /dashboard#settings, the hashtags are not sent to the server, so the user will have to load the index page first and then the settings page gets rendered which is not a good user experience since there's a delay. Also if you're going to have modals, you can use a query string, for example /dashboard?modal=show

Comment: The hash bang is [a lie](http://tumbledry.org/2011/05/12/screw_hashbangs_building). Don't use them.

Comment: And old browsers support is a lie also. While public parts of site can probably have extended support of retro browsers, such applications as "dashboard" (almost always this is an app which used by guys who knows why they should update their browser) can use latest stable features available. All in all even IE10 (more than 2 years old) [supports](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState) history API

Comment: Interesting points about the hash bang.  However, I should have pointed out in my post that my question equally applies to _any_ use of onhashchange and not necessarily google's hash bang proposal

Comment: Well, for your particular task I really don't see any preferable approach. Both will do all you need. Personally for me, I like history API because it can make links look better, and this is really most significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling) does a pretty good job of summing up the potential issues with using hash/hashbang, albeit it's pretty biased against them- often with good reason.

You are in a pretty fortunate position given that:

1. You don't have to worry about SEO concerns
2. Your app is internal to your organization

To me this makes your choice pretty clear cut depending on whether or not you can require those within your organization to upgrade their browsers to a version that is HTML5 compatible, if they haven't already. So, if you have that ability, use HTML5 History api. If you don't, use hash. If you want HTML5 pushState with an HTML4 onhashchange fallback, [you can do that as well](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/tree/master/scripts/bundled-uncompressed/html4+html5) though it'll require some extra work to ensure all your HTML5 links work for HTML4 users.